# Pass map to ansible via Jenkins ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, jenkins-pipeline

How can I get jenkin ansible-playbook plugin to pass a list of strings in the same way I would on the command line?

```
ansible-playbook ... \
-e '{"package_urls": ["http...windows.exe", "http...linux.rpm", "http...babbage.steam"]}'
```

In jenkins the playbook seems to take a map for extraVars and my escaping attempts haven't yet worked

```
ansiblePlaybook (..., extraVars: [
   package_urls: """["http...windows.exe", "http...linux.rpm", "http...babbage.steam"]""" )
```

Results in the following which lacks ' and ' and is not recognized as a list

```
... -e package_urls=["http...windows.exe", "http...linux.rpm", "http...babbage.steam"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in that it produces the correct command line.   The playbook plugin has an **extras** param which can be used to pass a variety of text down the the command line.  I usually use this for the '-vvv' verbosity modification.

```
ansiblePlaybook ( ..., 
    extras:  """-e '{"package_urls": ["http...windows.exe", "http...linux.rpm", "http...babbage.steam"]}'""")
```

The desired text is passed down to the command line with no modifications and the job pulls in its list.

This is probably not the optimal approach and either populating a var file or a json file which is read by the playbook feels like a cleaner approach